# Modify Bamboo release metadata

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo, continuous-delivery

For CD pipeline I built with Bamboo I'd like somehow to tag my release that eg. it ran successfully in UAT.

I think it would be fairly straightforward to just put a tag in git, but having this information on Bamboo-release level is more appealing.

I'm wondering, if it is possible to modify Bamboo release metadata after release is created?
How do you handle a case like this?

PS. I know that in Jenkins that could be separate step in the pipeline eg. "Deploy to UAT" -> "Run UAT tests" -> OK, but for the moment I'm stuck with Bamboo and its "deployment environments".

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo allows you to "Approve" a release.  Go to the release details page and click **Approved**.

[image]

Once you approve it, the release will show an icon next to it anywhere the release number is shown in a list page.

[image]

If you want to do this via code, Bamboo does have an API.

Comment: I know about "Approve" button, but what I'm after is something more sophisticated: I want to mark that release is eg. "tested on UAT", "approved by QA", "nonfunctional requirements met". On that basis someone could click "Approve" or "Rejected" accordingly.

Comment: Do you also use Jira?  It allows you to customize the workflow.

Comment: Yes but in JIRA the workflow is related to the particular story and I'm interested with setting this on release level, preferably by some API call so that it can be automated.

Comment: I don't see anything like what you describe in the API:  https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/bamboo-rest-resources/

Comment: One thing that we did is create a "Deploy" type of Jira that we can use in any project.  That Jira has the status of the release.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I think I will try something similar but with git tags, as I'd like to have this info per commit/build.